# How do I make a WPF ListBox with a TextBox stretch inside a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a `ListBox` that contains a single `TextBox` with a lot of text, which should be wrapped when possible. The `ListBox` is inside a `ScrollViewer` along with other controls (in the example below, it's a `Button`). I would like the `ListBox` to stretch horizontally with the `ScrollViewer`, and only show a horizontal scroll bar when the `ListBox` is smaller than a certain width. Here's the XAML I've got:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        >
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Test" />
            <ListBox MinWidth="500">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBox
                        Text="This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test."
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        />
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that the `ListBox` (and therefore the `TextBox`) go to their maximum width no matter the width of the `ScrollViewer`. The horizontal bar always shows up (unless, of course, the width of the `ScrollViewer` is past the width of the `ListBox`). I want the horizontal bar to show up only when the `ListBox` is smaller than a certain size.

Comment: Do you need that outside StackPanel?  It only contains one item.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not really. It's the topmost panel inside a `Window`, but I suppose that for this example the `ScrollViewer` could be the topmost element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial-and-error and other answers on StackOverflow, I arrived at the following solution:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        >
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Test" />
            <ListBox
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"
                MinWidth="500"
                >
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox
                            Text="This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test."
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            />
                    </Grid>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

The only changes are the additional properties on the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know  why do you need the ListBox i think that you can use this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Test" />
    <TextBox Text="This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Grid.Row="1"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The code I posted is a minimal problem for the sake of simplifying the question. My actual problem uses a ListBox to hold a list of items bound via ItemsSource.

Comment: If you wanna modify the listbox i recommed `ListBox.ItemTemplate` there you can create your custom design